# What's the difference between an "eSIM" and a "Digital SIM"?

Tags: iphone, ios, sim, esim

I thought that ESIM and Digital SIM were the same thing, to be distinguished from a physical SIM. However, my iPhone SE shows that I have an ESIM and a Digital SIM, and they have different IMEI numbers.

[image: Screenshot of iPhone SE settings showing both an ESIM and DIGITAL SIM with different IMEI numbers]

In the past, I think I remember that this used to show a section for what it called a "Physical SIM" but I think that section was replaced with what now says "Digital SIM". This was after changing SIM cards, carriers, and updating the APN settings.

Comment: It’s not clear what the question is here. What are you trying to do / solve?

Comment: What if you rename the two plans, what is then shown under About ??

Comment: The question is "What is the difference between an “eSIM” and a “Digital SIM”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An eSIM can be thought of as a type of digital SIM.

You can store multiple eSIMs on a phone, and thus have several listings of them (only one can be activated at the same time though).

The digital SIM listing is there even when you have no eSIMs installed. When you have 1 eSIM installed, you'll see both the basic capability of digital SIM shown as well as the actual eSIM.

So all in all this is perfectly normal.

Comment: So does this mean my physical soon is not activated?

Comment: No? ............ Are you experiencing a problem that you would like to have solved?

Comment: Nice contribution !

Comment: *SIM, not soon. I'm just confused because I don't see the IMEI for my physical SIM anywhere. New carrier is asking for my IMEI and I'm not sure which is the correct one to give them.

Comment: I assume you have a 2nd gen iPhone SE - you can then just push out the little SIM tray - the IMEI number is written on the tray itself.